# Retain last page state on navigate back in JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In my JSF page, I am displaying customers in a PrimeFaces datatable, the datatable has filter and sorting enabled, when an user click on a customer it will open customer details page in the same window, this is ok.

But when the user press back button, the filter and sorting is lost, my user want to retain the filter and sorting on the table, and don't want to do filter again and again, I know  details page can be open in new tab, that will solve this problem, but the user want to view the details in the same window.

**EDIT  :**

The Backing Bean is viewScoped

Comment: How about posting some code examples?

Comment: is it necessary to post code ?, do JSF retains the page state normally when navigate back ? note : ViewscopedBean

Comment: do you actually use the jquery datatables plugin? Or the jsf or PrimeFaces or IceFaces or Richfaces datatable? And here you see why posting code IS relevant

Comment: yes its primeface Datatable

Comment: i have edited the question, mentioning it is Primeface datatable

Comment: You added a very wrong tag. Please next time pay a little more attention to these things. Posting 'code' also helps to prevent errors

Comment: @Kukeltje here's the meta, you might be interested http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/301010/datatables-a-very-generic-tag

Answer (score 2):

a viewScoped bean is stored in the view map, so it is stored as long as the user stays in the same view, if the user navigates to a new view, the viewScoped bean is destroyed/trashed.

so i would suggest 2 ways to solve your problem:

1. make your bean sessionScoped
2. or better(due to bookmarking) requestScoped, and add the filter attributes to the URL, something like: filter.xhtml?color=1234&category=1233 ...etc or if you use friendly urls rewriting /filter/1234-1233...etc